# How to remove white parts in ArcMap 10.1?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, cartography, scale, mosaic

This is the part of my map.

[image]

On this picture you can see white strips. Some of this white parts are appeared on the intersection of 2 Mosaic Dataset (for eaxample, there is the real map in 1 Mosaic dataset, there is  the empty scan in 2 Mosaic dataset). **How to set option "no-data" of Mosaic Layer?** I want to display map without white parts.

***UPDATE***

On this picture you can see different MosaicDatasets. On the other forum people tell me that it is impossible to delete white parts in this case. (**because it is not a single mosaic dataset**)

Is it true?

Comment: Not sure this will help but for a single mosaicdataset you can alter the mosaic order (by going to the properties). If you set mosaic order to MAX then in areas where rasters are overlapping the cell with the maximum value is displayed and this can blend the rasters. This assumes your nodata is actually a zero value.

Comment: In unclipped topo maps the white border of one raster can mask the main map of another.  If they are RGB rasters you can set Layer Properties - Symbology - Display Background Value as No color.  The RGB might be 255, 255, 255, or 0,0,0.  If your topo has a colormap or discrete values there may be a particular value you need to display as no color (the metadata should say which) or failing that you might make the white display as no color and then change the order in the TOC of the two rasters until it works best.

Answer (score 3):

There is some good description of NoData in raster datasets in general [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000002v000000). Otherwise, I'd suggest using the [Define Mosaic Dataset NoData](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000008q000000) GP tool.

Comment: I set NoData, but I can not decide this problem. May be it is important to know: on the picture you can see different mosaic datasets